# If there exists a bijection between two sets $A$ and $B$, there exists a bijection between $\wp(A)$ and $\wp(B)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Where $A$ and $B$ are countably infinite and $\wp(A)$ and $\wp(B)$  are their powersets.

$\#$ represents cardinality.

My proof is this:
Let $c = \#\wp(A) = 2^{\aleph_0}$.
If there exists a bijection between $A$ and $B$, then this implies (this is given in the definition I am using) that $\#A = \#B = \aleph_0$
Thus, $2^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\#A} = 2^{\#B} = \#(2^A)=\#(2^B)=c$

Thus, because both $2^A$ and $2^B$ have the same cardinality, by definition, this means that there exists a bijection between $2^A$ and $2^B$ or $\wp(A)$ and $\wp(B)$.

Is this enough? I proved that $2^{\#A} = \#(2^A)$ for finite sets, is that enough for countably infinite sets?

Comment: You're putting the cart before the horse here. The _reason_ why you know that $|2^A|=|2^B|$ when $|A|=|B|$ is that you believe there is a bijection between them -- but now you're being asked to _prove_ that; just saying "I already know the thing I'm supposed to prove is true" does not constitute a proof.

Comment: So what I have to do is prove that there are injections between the two power sets and by Schroeder-Bernstein there is a bijection?

Comment: x @TheBosco: Yes, that would be one strategy. In this particular case, though, the easiest way to produce an injection $\mathcal P(A)\to\mathcal P(B)$ will actually already give you a bijection, so there'll be no need to appeal to Bernstein.

Comment: What about uncountable sets? This is a case where limiting the cardinality is more of a hindrance.

Answer (score -1):

Let $f:A \to B$ be a bijection and define $F:\wp(A) \to \wp(B)$ by

$F(M):=f(M)$.

Then $F$ is a bijection.

Comment: If you're so eager to post a quick answer, why not write an actual answer touching on the problems in the suggested proof in the question (which is asking for verifying the given proof is correct)? If you're uninterested in doing that, then how about only leaving a comment?

Comment: @AsafKaragila This is just a query for helping me write better answers in future, on MSE. Is it mandatory to provide hints only as a comment or can we write it as an answer too?

Comment: @kishlaya: Hints can be given as answers, sure. But you're expected to write them properly; and when a question is about proof verification...

Comment: @AsafKaragila ok, got it! Thanks.